# How can I procedurally narrow the pupil of an eye?

Tags: node-editor, vector-mapping

I made eyes and need them for different animals.

How can I make the pupil narrow?

[image: eye and shadernodes]

Comment: did you try simply using the Mapping node between the cross product and the ramp and change the X, Y or Z scale?

Comment: This is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have a node setup for one object to make the iris and the pupil. You would need to have just the iris as the background, and then another object parented to it to be the pupil. It would look like an eye, not two objects.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I understand, to move- shape pupil I need to manipulate geometry.